# Lecturer/Tutor at Online University, which word is more appropriate?

Tags: terminology, punctuation, articles, dates

In the following paragraph:

> I am Dr. John SMITH, Lecturer at [the name of a virtual university
> (abbr.)] since 2009, and Research Director at [the name of another
> university (abbr.)] in the years 2012-2014. I had my Ph.D. thesis at [the name of a university (abbr.)] in Paris, France, 2001.

1. Is it correct to use the word "Lecturer" with a Virtual University
   (online university), or "Tutor" is better in this case?
2. I see some people write in this way without using articles with
   "Lecturer" and "Research Director"; is that correct? If yes, what is
   the rule?
3. Are the punctuations and the way I mentioned the dates correct?

Comment: What is your job title at the virtual university? If they call you Lecturer, say you're "Lecturer at..." ; if they call you Tutor, say you're "Tutor at ..." ; if they call you Instructor, say you're "Instructor at ..." If you're translating from another language (like French), what title are you translating?

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin They use the title "Tutor", but do you think it is an appropriate title to use as a position for someone who gives lectures online at a university?

Comment: Please explain why the name of the (old) position is ambiguous.

Comment: @Lawrence It is not ambiguous, but I only think it is less common.

Comment: Whether any of us here thinks that the title is 'appropriate' is neither here nor there; if the university has decided to give Dr. Smith the title *Tutor*, then that's what his title is. That, of course, does not prevent Dr. Smith from explaining what his work includes (and, in fact, it may be a good idea to do so, if his job is unlike what tutors do elsewhere). Dr. Smith, however, does not have the power to correct the arguably bad choice of terminology on part of the university's administration, by giving himself the title of a Lecturer.

Comment: Since it’s not ambiguous, report the title that was actually assigned.

Comment: Alternately, instead of using the title "Tutor" you could use a general description "lecturer" (note the lower case) if that accurately describes what you have been doing.

Comment: Thank you all for these details. Could anyone please answer my last comment to JeremyC's answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Does Dr Smith have an official job title? If, as is probable, he does, then that should be used here, even if you or anyone else might think that it is a bit odd in the context of a wholly online university.
   If, as is possible, the job title is a bit unusual  (eg "Sub-Dean", "Student", "Moral Tutor") then it would be quite OK to translate it into a better known version provided you are quite sure that your "translation" won't cause confusion with other possibly oddly titled roles at that university. At my first university, for example, the Senior Tutors' role did not involve any teaching or lecturing at all, so if you "translated" the job title Senior Lecturer as Senior Tutor you would cause confusion.
2. If you are citing a job title then it must be cited exactly. Some job titles include the definite article, but very many do not. If there is no article in the title it must be omitted. I used to deal with an organisation where there was a difference, including a big difference in salary, between "Director, Personnel" and "Director of Personnel". You should use precisely the terminology of the university. If, on the other hand, you are using words to describe someone's function then, you can say what you like. So, for example, Paul Dirac's job title at Cambridge University was "Lucasian Professor of Mathematics", but you could quite properly describe him as you could describe his role as "the senior professor of applied mathematics".
3. I think the punctuation and dates are OK but it is not usual in English to say "I had my PhD thesis...". There may be a special word used in the university where Dr Smith did his PhD. Sometimes one sees "defended". You could say "I was awarded a PhD ...".

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you for these details. Do you mean "I was awarded the Ph.D. degree at [the name of the university]"?

Comment: If one's job title is potentially confusing, it is probably the best to provide both the title and an explanation of what one's actual role is. Also, to make explicit what is already implied in (2), capitalising a word such as *Lecturer* or *Tutor* implies that it is a formally awarded title; if one uses such a word in an informal explanation of what one does, it should not be capitalised.

Comment: Could you please answer my question in the first comment? And can I write "[someone] was awarded a BSc degree in Computer Science at [the name of his/her university]" in a recommendation letter?

Comment: I think "I was awarded the Ph.D. degree in 2001 from/by [the name of the university (abbr.)] in Paris, France." and "[someone] was awarded a BSc degree in Computer Science from/by [the name of his/her university]" are more appropriate. Am I right?

Comment: @catfour Taking your points in order: that formulation is good; yes, but you could also write "...acquired a BSc degree..."; the word 'awarded' is OK but it very slightly suggests some element of an honorary award, so that is why it might be preferable to use 'acquired', 'earned' or some similar verb form implying that the recipient's own efforts were the reason for the awards.

Comment: @jsw29 I quite agree with you